# Excel 2013 'Disable AutoRecover for this workbook only' does not work

Tags: python-3.x, excel, excel-2013

I'm using Python to write data to and open an excel file, and also to close it if already open using os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM excel.exe').

Problem is, when the excel file then opened, Document Recover will pop up even though I've already ticked Options > Save > Disable AutoRecover for this workbook only.

Is this an excel bug?

Comment: You may need to save and re-open the document with that setting

Comment: I've tried that, no difference.